# Múltiples Notificaciones solo muestra la ùltima, no se actualiza

Tags: java, android, push-notification

¿Qué debo hacer para que cuando mi aplicación mande una segunda (tercera..cuarta... etc) notificación no se sustituya y se vayan incluyendo todas?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    DatePicker datePicker;
    TimePicker timePicker;
    Button btnStart;
    Uri uriAlarm;
    final static int RQS_1 = 1;
    EditText textonombre;
    EditText textodescripcion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notif_main);

        datePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
        timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        uriAlarm = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        textonombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textonombre);
        textodescripcion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textodescripcion);



        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    setAlarm(uriAlarm);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarma ACTIVADA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
    }

    private void setAlarm(Uri passuri){

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),
                datePicker.getMonth(),
                datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                00);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), pruebaintento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(),
                RQS_1,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,id,repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("NOMBRE")
                .setContentText("DESCRIPCIÓN")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(id,builder.build());

    }
}
```

---

Edito: @Elenasys

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    int id= 1;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,id++,repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("NOMBRE")
                .setContentText("DESCRIPCIÓN")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(id++,builder.build());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema se encuentra aquí:

```
notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

**Debes asegurar que el id sea diferente al generar una nueva notificación.**

Incluso es importante el id sea diferente ya que si la notificación contiene datos diferentes estos pueden no actualizarse aunque los envíes correctamente en posteriores notificaciones.

---

En código puedes definir

```
  notificationManager.notify(id++, builder.build());
```

o enviar el id de la notificación a enviar que estaría definida como llave primaria autoincrementable.

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys y como debería hacerlo de manera correcta? Guardando las notificaciones en la database?

Comment: Lo que uso en cada notificación es el id de cada notificación que tiene un id autoincremental, pero tu podrías en código generar un id incrementado a uno en cada notificación.

Comment: y cómo puedo hacer que se auto-incremente el ID?

Comment: En código puedes hacer   (id++, builder.build()); o enviar el id de la notificación a enviar que estaría definida como llave primaria autoincrementable

Comment: tu primera opción añadiendole int id= 001; pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Debe ser entero 1,2,3..etc. consecutivo...

Comment: sigue igual, he añadido el código modificado a la pregunta, hago algo mal?

Comment: Solo revisa que el id que se registra para cada notificación sea diferente.

Comment: Cómo debería revisar que son diferentes? @Elenasys

Comment: Ahh puedes realizar depuración en la linea y ver el valor de la variable id :)

Comment: Pero ya se que es la misma ID, ya que la sustituye, no se añade una nueva

Comment: No debe ser la misma debe ser diferente cada vez que llamas notify() : notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());

Answer (score 0):

tiene mucho tiempo esta pregunta, entre con el mismo problema y pude solucionarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
Random ran=new Random();
int nu=ran.nextInt(1000)+1;
```

genere un numero random, curiosamente creando un int por si solo y agregandole el ++ no funcionaba, y para terminar se pasa la variable "nu" al notify.

```
manager.notify(nu,builder.build());
```

a mi me funciono, ojala le sirva alguien