# ¿Cómo crear varias alarmas y poder editarlos después?

Tags: android, sqlite

¿cómo puedo crear varias alarmas, creo una alarma con intervalo de repetición, pero al crear la segunda, sobreescribe la primera y solo esa se queda activa?

Al tratar de borrarla y/o editarla no puede tener acceso a el.

alguién que pueda ayudarme, estoy usando `AlarmManager`

el registro de fecha y hora, asi como el intervalo los estoy gurdando en una bd sqlite

Comment: Buenas, revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: ok muchas gracias, los tendré en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

> ¿cómo puedo crear varias alarmas, creo una alarma con intervalo de repetición, pero al crear la segunda, sobreescribe la primera y solo esa se queda activa?

**La solución es simplemente asignar un ID diferente a cada alarma, para que no sea sobre escrita.**

```
notificationManager.notify(idAlarma, builder.build());
```

Recuerda también que para cancelar la alarma es indispensable el mismo ID con el cual la activaste.

---

Te sugiero ver esta pregunta:
[Múltiples Notificaciones en la barra Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42956/m%C3%BAltiples-notificaciones-en-la-barra-android)