# Problema con notificaciones android

Tags: android

Hola necesitaria una ayuda con la notificaciones en android, estoy con una app que necesito que mande varias notificaciones durante el dia, y solo consigo que si por ejemplo mando tres notificaciones me llegue la ultima, la primera y la segunda son ignoradas, supongo que por que no estoy haciendo bien los PendingIntents, pero ya he buscado muchas soluciones y realmente sigo igual.

Este es el metodo que va dentro del OnReceive de la clase que extiende a Broadcast:

```
public void bigPicture (Context context, Uri alarmSound,Bitmap bitmapArray,CharSequence cs){

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int id = 1;
        int idMas = ++id;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify)
                .setContentText(cs)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmapArray));

        notificationManager.notify(idMas,mNotifyBuilder.build());
    }
```

Y este otro codigo  va en la actividad dentro un onclick:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calendar1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

                                Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calendar2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

                                Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calendar3.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());


                                calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
                                calendar1.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE,48);
                                calendar1.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND,0);

                                calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
                                calendar2.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE,48);
                                calendar2.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND,30);

                                calendar3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
                                calendar3.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE,49);
                                calendar3.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND,00);


                                int uniqueInt = new Random().nextInt(543254);


                                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Notificaciones_Activity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
                                intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent1.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));


                                PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Notificaciones_Activity.this,uniqueInt
                                        ,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Notificaciones_Activity.this,uniqueInt
                                        ,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                                PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Notificaciones_Activity.this,uniqueInt
                                        ,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                                AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                AlarmManager alarmManager3 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                                alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent1);
                                alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar2.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent2);
                                alarmManager3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar3.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent3);
```

Si en lugar de poner setReapeating() pongo setExact() si me funciona, pero saltan
 notificaciones antiguas fuera de  tiempo.

Espero vuestra ayuda, grácias.

Comment: Hola Ricersa, te sugiero revisar en el sitio , estonfue respondido aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42956/múltiples-notificaciones-solo-muestra-la-ùltima

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que le estás poniendo el mismo ID a todas las notificaciones por lo que se sobreescriben.

```
int id = 1;
int idMas = ++id;
```

Pero id siempre es 1 y idMas siempre es 2.
Prueba a definir una variable id estática en la clase:

```
private static final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

Y luego usarla como id:

```
int id = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza `setExact`. Prueba con este código:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent i = ...

PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Notificaciones_Activity.this, 1, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Notificaciones_Activity.this, 2, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pi3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Notificaciones_Activity.this, 3, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pi1);
am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), pi2);
am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar3.getTimeInMillis(), pi3);
```

Asegurate que al iniciar a escribir los objeto Calendar (calendar1, ...) seleccionalos de la ventana emergente, no los escribas 
completamente.

Para reiniciar la Activity a las 0 horas:

```
    @Override            
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AlarmManager am5 = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notificaciones_Activity.class);

    Calendar cal5 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal5.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,00);
    cal5.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
    cal5.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    PendingIntent peIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 8, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    am5.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal5.getTimeInMillis(), peIntent);
    }
```

Puedes agregar el siguiente código para que NO se lanzen las notificaciones ya pasadas:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (now <= calendar1.getTimeInMillis()) {
        am.setExact(AlarmManager ...
    }
```

Comment: He hecho lo que me has dicho aunque no entiendo lo de seleccionar los objetos calendar del la (¿ventana emergente?), el codigo funciona, pero sigo teniendo un problema, este codigo esta en un boton, en su onclick. Cuando le das al boton por primera vez las tres notificaciones funcionan, cuando voy a hacer otra prueba y vuelvo a darle al boton, a los pocos segundos aparece una notificacion no programada y las tres que si han sido programadas. Otra pregunta, ¿con setExact() estas notificaciones se repiran diariamente?.

Comment: Cuando empiezas a escribir código, Android Studio te despliega una
lista de opciones, ejemplo: al escribir la letra "c" aparece esa "ventana" para que selecciones alguna (en tu caso deben aparecer, entre otras, 
calendar1,calendar2, calendar3 ...). Pero en este caso si seleccionastes las correctas porque si se estan lanzando las 3 notificaciones.

Comment: Debes de iniciar el emulador/celular a los 0 segundos del minuto que seleccionastes, no despues, para evitar esa notificación extra.
Las notificaciones se repetirán siempre y cuando la activity se reinicie. Una forma es reiniciar la app a las 0 horas de cada día. A manera de prueba, y con diferencias de segundos en los calendar, sustituye los cal5.set por estos: `cal5.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal5.set(Calendar.SECOND,56);`
Inicia el emulador a los 0 segundos.La activity se recreara cada minuto.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿cómo puedo crear varias alarmas, creo una alarma pero al crear la segunda, sobreescribe la primera y solo la ùltima queda activa?

**La solución es simplemente asignar un ID diferente a cada alarma, para que no sea sobre escrita.**

```
notificationManager.notify(idAlarma,mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

Recuerda también que para cancelar la alarma es indispensable el mismo ID con el cual la activaste.

---

Te sugiero ver esta pregunta:
[Múltiples Notificaciones solo muestra la ùltima](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42956/m%C3%BAltiples-notificaciones-en-la-barra-android)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a vuestros comentarios consegui que las notificaciones se lanzaran todas, pero me surgen más problemas:

El primero es que necesito que esas notificaciones se lancen también cuando el dispositivo se renicia, para ello he modificado el manifest xml asi:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".TestService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootStartUpReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Y con ello se que el broadCastReceiver se reinicia gracias a un Toast, pero las notificaciones no llegan cuando reinicias el dispositivo.

El segundo problema es que el metodo setReapeating() hace que las notificaciones antiguas se muestren en cuanto reinicias el dispositivo y me gustaria que eso no pasase.
El codigo relativo a las notificaciones quedo asi:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button boton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_bt);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

  noty1();
        }
    });
}
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();


public  void noty1(){

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


    calendar1.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE,17);
    calendar1.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND,0);

    calendar2.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE,18);
    calendar2.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND,0);

    calendar3.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE,19);
    calendar3.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND,0);

    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BootStartUpReciever.class);


    PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 2, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pi3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 3, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,calendar1.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi1);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,calendar2.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi2);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,calendar3.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi3);

   /* am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pi1);
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), pi2);
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, calendar3.getTimeInMillis(), pi3);*/
}
```

}

```
public class TestService extends Service {
public TestService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio onCreate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onCreate();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Destroy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showNotification();

    return TestService.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
private static final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);


private void showNotification(){



    NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    int id = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();


    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this.getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_3d_rotation)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setColor(this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            //.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Texto"));

    mManager.notify(id,mNotifyBuilder.build());
    Toast.makeText(TestService.this,"showNotification",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //  }


}
```

}

```
public class BootStartUpReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "RestartAppReceiver";

public BootStartUpReciever() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving

   Intent service = new Intent(context, TestService.class);
    context.startService(service);

}

}
```

En definitiva lo que quiero es poder lanzar varias notificaciones cada una a una hora determinada, que esas notificaciones se repitan diariamente, que cuando el usuario reinicie el sistema esas notificaciones sigan funcionando y al reiniciar el dispositivo no se muestren notificaciones antiguas sino solo las que estan por venir.

Nunca habia estado tan liado con algun problema, las notificaciones me llevan de cabeza ya durante varias semanas y me encuentro lejos de encontrar la solución.

Agradeceria si alguien pudiese modificar los errores encontrados en el codigo. Que seguramente no seran pocos...
Gracias.

Comment: Parece ser que el unico problema que me queda por solucionar es que cuando reinicio el dispositivo , se reinicia el broadcastreceiver pero solo salta una notificacion inmediatamente, el resto de notificaciones que quedan por salir no se activan.

Comment: Prueba con el siguiente código:
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (now <=calendar1.getTimeInMillis() || now <= calendar2...) {
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager ...
    }
Significa que si SOLO en este momento el tiempo (now) es menor (esta antes) al de los calendar1 y 2, se notificará.
Prueba con || ó con &&