# Como actualizar una push notificación?

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Mi app es de mensajes entre usuario y lanza notificaciones al detectar una nueva inserción en la base de datos (muestra los mensajes recibidos), pero al momento de que se inserta nuevamente un nuevo registro (mensaje) este me crea una nueva notificación, por lo cual necesito actualizar dicha notificación con el nuevo mensaje recibido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int icono = R.drawable.notification_icon;
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, in, 0);

mBuilder = (android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder) new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setSmallIcon(icono)
           .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
           //.setContentTitle(titulo)
           .setContentText(mensaje_noti)
           .setStyle(new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(texto))
           .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250, 100, 500})
           .setAutoCancel(true);

android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
        new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

// Sets a title for the Inbox in expanded layout
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(nombre_chat);
```

Al expander la notificación me muestra la lista de mensajes recibidos

```
// Moves events into the expanded layout
for (int i=0; i < chatss.length; i++) {
     inboxStyle.addLine(chatss[i]);
}

// Moves the expanded layout object into the notification object.
mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
mNotifyMgr.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

Incremento el identificador de la notificación, supongo aquí está mi error, pero no tengo idea de como actualizar dicha notificación

```
id++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si, creeria que el error es incrementar el valor de `id` como muestras.

Consultando [la documentacion](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#Updating), se recomiendo el utilizar el mismo `id` al mostrar una notificacion que deseas actualizar:

Español:

> Para actualizar la notificacion despues de que se ha lanzado, llama `NotificationManagerCompat.notify()` otra vez, utilizando una notificacion con el mismo id que utilizaste previamente.

Original, en ingles:

> To update this notification after you've issued it, call `NotificationManagerCompat.notify()` again, passing it a notification with the same ID you used previously.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, no sé si sea una buena práctica pero terminé creando un array donde el index de dicho array lo utilizo como el id de la notificación.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es similar a este:

[Múltiples Notificaciones solo muestra la ùltima](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42956/m%C3%BAltiples-notificaciones-solo-muestra-la-%C3%B9ltima)

Recuerda que [**para actualizar la notificación, debes asegurar que el `id` sea diferente al generar una nueva notificación.**](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification?hl=es#Updating)

```
mNotifyMgr.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
mNotifyMgr.notify(id++, mBuilder.build());
```

o puedes recibir el id y asignarlo al método notify`( )`.