# No se muestran las notificaciones de FireBase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-messaging

Hola a todos los que se detuvieron ayudarme.

Estoy intentando enviar notificaciones de firebase a android, funciona pero tengo que deslizar las notificaciones y buscarla porque cuando llegan no se muestran.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

     

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            // Since the notification is received directly from
            // FCM, the title and the body can be fetched
            // directly as below.
            showNotification(
                    remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                    remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

   
    private RemoteViews getCustomDesign(String title,
            String message) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.message, message);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        return remoteViews;
    }

 
    public void showNotification(String title,
            String message) {
        // Pass the intent to switch to the MainActivity
        Intent intent
                = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        // Assign channel ID
        String channel_id = "notification_channel";
        // Here FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag is set to clear
        // the activities present in the activity stack,
        // on the top of the Activity that is to be launched
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        // Pass the intent to PendingIntent to start the
        // next Activity
        PendingIntent pendingIntent
                = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

      
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder
                = new NotificationCompat
                .Builder(getApplicationContext(),
                channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000,
                        1000, 1000})
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

      
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            builder = builder.setContent(
                    getCustomDesign(title, message));
        } 
        else {
            builder = builder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }
      
        NotificationManager notificationManager
                = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel
                    = new NotificationChannel(
                    channel_id, "web_app",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                    notificationChannel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

> Esto esto es lo que esta en el manifest

```
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo noto un detalle importante, estas definiendo 0 como id de notificación siempre lo cual es incorrecto:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent
                = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

...
...
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

debes definir un `id` diferente para cada notificación, de otra forma si defines el mismo `id`, no se crea una nueva notificación solo se sobre escribe la primera que recibes, realiza este cambio definiendo una variable que aumenta para crear cada notificación:

```
 int id= 1;
 ...
 ...

    PendingIntent pendingIntent
                    = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, i++, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
...
...
notificationManager.notify(i++, builder.build());
```

Revisa:

[Múltiples Notificaciones solo muestra la ùltima, no se actualiza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42956/m%C3%BAltiples-notificaciones-solo-muestra-la-%C3%B9ltima-no-se-actualiza)

Comment: funciona bro, me podrías decir como evito que lleguen las notificaciones si la aplicación esta abierta, te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: No quieres que lleguen si esta abierta la app? por que razòn no deseas eso me da curiosidad?

Comment: No quiero que se vean porque mandaré notificaciones a los teléfonos que tengan la app cerrada para que visiten la app, entonces si tienes la app abierta es de mal gusto ver una notificación sugiriendo que la obras o algo.

Answer (score -1):

puede que las notificaciones no estén llegando a tu clase que muestras. Podrías verificar este caso agregando un `Log.d` o algún mensaje que muestre que el método `onMessageReceived` se esta ejecutando.

Por otra parte, podrías verificar el tipo de notification que estas enviando, ya sea desde la misma consola de Firebase o desde algún server. Existen dos tipos, Notification y Data. Puede que estes usando el que lo maneja el sistema y por eso te manda los valores por defecto.

Para más detalle puede verificar -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

PD: Si estas probando tu proyecto en un emulador de android, recuerda que debes descargar un sistema operativo que contenga Playstore, de caso contrario no se mostrarán las notificaciones. También existe el caso ( me ocurrió en Android 5), donde el emulador esta configurado para ahorrar la energía de las aplicaciones, en consecuencia limita a mostrar algunas notificaciones.

Espero que sea de ayuda :)

Comment: las notificaciones estan llegando bro

Comment: Esto únicamente confirmaría si se reciben o no las notificaciones pero ¿como se soluciona?, revisar [answer], saludos.