# No se puede mostrar notificaciones en android - Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, android-notifications

Estoy tratando de mostrar notificaiones que vienen de la api de FCM(firebase cloud messaging) en mi aplicacion en primer plano, sin embargo no se muestra aun si lo envio por la consola de firebase, en este caso solo se muestra cuando la app se encuentra en segundo plano.

este es el codigo que tengo

```
package com.example.helloworld.services

class NotificationFirebase: FirebaseMessagingService() {
    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "example_channel"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 0
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private val exampleChannel = NotificationChannel(
        CHANNEL_ID,
        "Example",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    ).apply {
        // agrega aquí todas las configuraciones que necesites
        enableVibration(true)
        description = "just an example"
    }
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: https://goo.gl/39bRNJ
        Log.d("Notifyey", "From: ${remoteMessage.from}")

        if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            val titulo = remoteMessage.data.get("title")
            val mensaje = remoteMessage.data.get("message")
            Log.d("Notifyey", "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage.data}")
            if (titulo!="" && mensaje!="") {
                val manager = ContextCompat
                    .getSystemService(applicationContext, NotificationManager::class.java)!!
                remoteMessage.notification?.run {
                    Log.d("Notifyey", "Message title: ${titulo}")
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                        manager.createNotificationChannel(exampleChannel)
                    val notification = buildNotification(titulo!!, mensaje!!)
                    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
                }

            }
        }
        remoteMessage.notification?.let {
            Log.d("Body Notifyey", "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
        }
    }
    private fun buildNotification(title: String, body: String): Notification {
        return NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            //.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .build()
    }
}
```

vale aclarar que en consola no tengo ningun error y que si recibo las natificaciones de mi servidor pero las de la consola no, ya que no se imprime ningun log cuando la notificacion se manda desde la consola de firebase.

Lo que tengo en el manifest es lo siguiente

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworld">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HelloWorld">
        <activity
            android:name=".InfoProfile"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name=".UserMain" />
        <activity android:name=".Inicio">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".services.NotificationFirebase"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

cuando mando una notificacion de prueba con firebase (donde te piden introducir un token de FCM) y estoy en primer plano no me aparece sin embargo cuando envia la notificacion real desde la consola la app se cierra y me aparece el siguiente error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
    Process: com.example.helloworld, PID: 30892
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.helloworld.services.NotificationFirebase.onMessageReceived(NotificationFirebase.kt:48)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.1:13)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.1:8)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.1:3)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.1:3)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:6)
```

Comment: se imprimen todos los logs? Cuando envías un mensaje desde la consola `remoteMessage.data` debería estár vacio. Si la condición del primer `if` no se cumple la notificación nunca se va a mostrar..

Comment: si lo envio desde la consola no se imprime ningun log

Comment: entonces no lo estás recibiendo

Comment: pues al parecer no, pero si la app esta en segundo plano si me lo muestra

Comment: ya edite la pregunta

Comment: revisa si los marca como recibidos en el dashboard de firebase. Y que sucede si envias las notificaciones desde tu servidor? Logras recibirlas?

Comment: Bueno al enviarlo desde mi servidor si lo recibo ya que se muestra el primer log, con firebase al enviar la notififcacion se cierra la app, voy a ver que me da por la consola

Comment: Antes enviaba la notificación de prueba con firebase y no pasaba nada ahora que envío la notificación con firebase se cierra la app

Comment: el código de `NotificationFirebase` está actualizado o cambiaste algo después? Cuál es la linea 48?

Comment: linea 48 ```val notification = buildNotification(titulo!!, mensaje!!)```, y no he cambiado nada todo esta igual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El título y el cuerpo de la notificación se encuentran en `remoteMessage.notification.title` y `remoteMessage.notification.body`. La propiedad `remoteMessage.data` se usa para enviar información adicional no relacionada directamente con la notificación. Esto significa que el valor de los siguientes campos es `null`

```
val titulo = remoteMessage.data.get("title")
val mensaje = remoteMessage.data.get("message")
```

Luego haces esta validación pero nunca comprobaste si el valor era nulo. `null` es distinto de `""` entonces la condición se cumple sin problemas

```
if (titulo!="" && mensaje!="")
```

Entonces cuando aplicas este operador `!!` sobre el valor `null` se produce la `NullPointerException`

```
val notification = buildNotification(titulo!!, mensaje!!)
```

La solución es crear la notificación con los datos que recibiste en `remoteMessage.notification`

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    Log.d("Notifyey", "From: ${remoteMessage.from}")
    remoteMessage.notification?.run {
        Log.d("Notifyey", "Message title: $title")
        val manager = ContextCompat
            .getSystemService(applicationContext, NotificationManager::class.java)!!
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(exampleChannel)
        val notification = buildNotification(title!!, body!!)
        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }
}
```

Cuando envíes una notificación desde tu servidor debe tener un formato como este:

```
let message = {
  notification: {
    title: 'title',
    body: 'body'
  },
  data: {}, // opcional
  token: 'token'
};
```

**No** uses el campo `data` para enviar el título y mensaje.
Más info en la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#when-to-use-common-fields)

Comment: Holas, lo siento estaba revisando mis preguntas y me surgió una duda. Se supone que kotlin se caracteriza por manejar los valores nulos, entonces ¿existe una forma de recibir la notificacion pero con el codigo fuera de la `override fun onMessageReceived`?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, ni la relación con los valores nulos.

Comment: osea existe una forma de crear la notificacion si o si, a pesar que los valores sean nulos, asignar algun valor por defult?

Comment: Claro, usa el [operador elvis](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) para asignar el valor por defecto. Aunque esos valores no deberían ser nulos.

Comment: ok, gracias. :)

Comment: Gracias a ti por aportar tanto a la comunidad. You are [the best](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/week/es-stackoverflow/2021-05-16/)!

Comment: Wow, no creí aportar tanto con la corta edad que tengo

Answer (score 0):

No me parece que el problema se provoque cuando tu aplicaciòn se encuentre en primer plano, el problema es debido a que usas el mismo id para todas las notificaciones (en este caso la variable `NOTIFICATION_ID` ), en tu còdigo usas el valor 0, si esta notificaciòn se genero previamente no se volvera a crear una nueva.

```
manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
```

para cuestiones de prueba uso una funciòn que retorna un numero aleatorio:

```
fun rand(from: Int, to: Int) : Int {
    val random = Random()
    return random.nextInt(to - from) + from
}
```

y lo defino:

```
  manager.notify(rand(0,1000), notification)
```

Revisa tambièn este ejemplo donde se usa una variable que es incrementada cuando se genera una nueva notificaciòn:

[Múltiples Notificaciones solo muestra la ùltima, no se actualiza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42956/m%C3%BAltiples-notificaciones-solo-muestra-la-%C3%B9ltima-no-se-actualiza)

---

Por cierto, no se aconsejable usar :

```
 NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
```

si defines tus notificaciòn como de "alta importancia" y abusas de esto, Google puede definir tus notificaciones con una importancia menor.

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré pero no creo que sea el problema ya que no se me muestra ninguna notificación

Comment: ok, es importante en cada notificaciòn cambiar el ID, para que no se sobreescriban.